# Opacity of Textured objects

Tags: shaders

I have 2 objects in the scene red cylinder and blue cube. They both have a basic colour in the Principal Shader. How can I lower the opacity of the red cylinder so I can see the blue cube behind it?[image]

Comment: You cant, you have to mix it with Transparent BSDF with a Mix Shader.

Answer (score -1):

OK I got there. Make the objects that you want to see through Glass then set blend mode to additive.....adjust roughness and shadows to taste......[image]